# Maria-DB increasing innodb_io_capacity?

Tags: mariadb, freebsd

I got two fast NVMe drives, and would like to increase the default value for innodb_io_capacity which is 200 (defined mostly for old SATA hdds) up to 15000, to get a better I/O bandwidth.

However, my question is, should innodb_flush_sync be turned off if innodb_io_capacity is set? If so, why?

OS: FreeBSD 13
Maria-DB ver: 10.5.12_1

Comment: Both docs, [innodb_flush_sync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_sync) and [innodb_io_capacity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity) link to [14.8.8 Configuring InnoDB I/O Capacity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-configuring-io-capacity.html) , which give a nice description on how to configure those settings, for MySQL, but most of it applies to MariaDB and, if not, please find the appropriate MariaDB docs.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't get this: "The innodb_flush_sync variable, which is enabled by default, causes the innodb_io_capacity setting to be ignored during bursts of I/O activity that occur at checkpoints. To adhere to the I/O rate defined by the innodb_io_capacity setting, disable innodb_flush_sync."

Comment: I think, but I am not an expert, that the setting `innodb-io-capacity-max` is used during the "bursts of I/O activity that occur at checkpoints".   Disabling innodb_flush_sync is needed to adhere to the I/O rate defined by the innodb_io_capacity setting.